# Automate Importing Multiple Excel Worksheets into SQL

Tags: sql-server, vba, vb6, excel, dts

I need to allow a user to select an Excel file, and then upload All Worksheets to a SQL table.  I'm not sure how to do this.  The format of each sheet is exactly the same.  And the worksheet format matches the SQL table format.

Comment: No, that isn't available.  DTS or some other method.

Comment: No answers on labor day?  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ODBC Provider for Excel files. Here is some code written in javascript to import a Excel file to a SQL Server Table. Each Worksheet is treated as a single table. There are some troubles with data types because the ODBC Driver deduces the data type of each column by reading it's first values, so if a column has numbers in the first rows of data the whole column will be read as numeric and every "non numeric" value will be read as NULL.

```
var objCat = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection"); 
var objRSExcel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");
objRSExcel.CursorLocation = 3;
var file =  "imported_file.xls";
var TableName = "[Sheet1$]"

// Database Creation
objCat.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";                    
objCat.Open();
objRSExcel.Open("SELECT * FROM " + TableName, objCat);

var rsInsert = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");
rsInsert.Open("SELECT * FROM [TARGET_TABLE]", cn, 1, 3);

while (!objRSExcel.EOF) {
    rsInsert.AddNew();
    for (var j=0;j<objRSExcel.Fields.Count; j++) {
        rsInsert.Fields(j).Value = objRSExcel.Fields(j).Value;
    }
    rsInsert.Update();
    objRSExcel.MoveNext();
}
objRSExcel.Close();
rsInsert.Close();
```

Comment: "There are some troubles with data types because the ODBC Driver deducts the data type of each column by reading it's first values, so if a column has numbers in the first rows of data the whole column will be read as numeric and every "non numeric" value will be read as NULL."

LOL, that doesn't seem good!

Comment: Yeah, you know, MS libraries are far for perfection.